# SerializationException when raising event in other instance via IPC

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ipc, remoting

I'm trying to send some information from a newly launched instance of my application to the currently running instance (namely one argument in the form of a string) by way of ipc.

```
Class RemoteObject
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject
    Public Event ParamEvent As RemoteObject.ParamEventHandler
    Public Property path As String = ""
    Delegate Sub ParamEventHandler()
    Public Sub FireEvent()
        RaiseEvent ParamEvent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Friend WithEvents on MainWindow:

```
 Friend WithEvents theRemoteObject As RemoteObject
```

I'm setting it up in my first instance like this.

```
theRemoteObject = New RemoteObject
theRemoteObject.path = "blah"
theChannel = New IpcChannel("localhost:9090")
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(theChannel, False)
RemotingServices.Marshal(theRemoteObject, "ParamReceiver")
```

And in my second instance:

```
Dim uri As String = "ipc://localhost:9090/ParamReceiver"
theChannel = New IpcChannel
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(theChannel, False)
theRemoteObject = DirectCast(RemotingServices.Connect(GetType(RemoteObject), uri), RemoteObject)
theRemoteObject.path = "blarg"
theRemoteObject.FireEvent()
```

Everything works properly; when the second instance starts the path property changes from "blah" to "blarg" in both instances. However, when I add this event handler in MainWindow:

```
Public Sub ParamHandler() Handles theRemoteObject.ParamEvent
    'do stuff here
End Sub
```

It halts on this line in the second instance:

```
theRemoteObject = DirectCast(RemotingServices.Connect(GetType(RemoteObject), uri), RemoteObject)
```

With the following exception:

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type 'Cutlist3.MainWindow' in Assembly 'Cutlist3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

I don't know what this means or where to start in debugging it. Any information you could provide would be super helpful and appreciated!

Comment: The exception means exactly what it says.

Comment: cant tell from `Cutlist3.MainWindow` what exactly you are trying to serialize, but forms and controls are not serializable. Or maybe `Cutlist` is simply not marked.

Comment: I'm not intentionally attempting to serialize my form. What is it about adding this event that makes it attempt to serialize my form? Do I need to set this up differently in order to make it not serialize? I don't really understand why it would do this.

Comment: Cutlist3.MainWindow is my form. I accept that forms are not serializable, but I don't know why that matters in this context. I'm simply adding an event handler to the form. What about that causes my form to be serialized? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I solved my problem by creating a new object declaration in the second instance `Dim SecondObject as RemoteObject = DirectCast` ... instead of using the original `Friend WithEvents theRemoteObject` declaration.